# combinging php session variable within html footer

Tags: php, html

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <footer>
            <p>
                <font size="2px">The shared documents above are 
                the property of <b><a href="<?php $_SESSION["Website"] ?>"><?php echo $_SESSION["companyname"] ?></a></b>
                and any files are confidential and intended solely for the use of the individual or entity to whom they are addressed.
                If you have received this link in error please notify our <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">admin team</a>.
            </p>
            <p>
               <font size="2px">If you are not the named addressee you should not disseminate, download, distribute or copy any documentation and should delete the email immediately.
               <font size="2.5px" color="PaleGoldenRod" ><b>  IMSdrive is owned by <a href="http://www.jkgsoft.com">JKGsoft</a> All rights reserved 2015.</b>
            </p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which for the most part works the way it should, however on the first session value, that places the company website within the htref element, although it is displaying as it should on the screen, it is not pointing to the correct website, screenshot [here](http://prntscr.com/7ab7lp).

I know that the `$_SESSION["Website"]` is working as I have tried echoing it in the header, was just wondering if someone can tell me why it is not escaping this website, when you hover over or click the link it basically takes you to the page you are already on.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you write `session_start()` at the top of your page???

Comment: You aren't echoing it in the footer. Put `<?php echo $_SESSION["Website"]; ?>`

Comment: Thanks that's sorted it, can't believe I didn't see I missed the echo, cheers bud

Comment: No problem, its always the little things that catch us out

Comment: @user3691947 unrelated comment. The `font`-tag is deprecated in HTML. You should either use inline or external styles instead. e.g. `<p style="font-size: 2px">`,

Answer (score 0):

Use `<?php session_start(); ?>`
in top of this page.